# Manipulating data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

That is my database:

```
    Number        Name  Points Math  Points BG  Wish
0        1       Огнян           50         65   MT
1        2      Момчил           61         27   MT
2        3    Радослав           68         68   MT
3        4       Павел           28         16   MT
4       10      Виктор           67         76   MT
5       11       Петър           26         68   BT
6       12       Антон           64         58   BT
7       13       Васил           29         42   BT
8       20    Виктория           62         67   BT
```

That's my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input_data.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
df['Total'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].sum(axis=1)
df = df.sort_values(['Total', 'Name'], ascending=[0, 1])
df_5.to_excel("BT RANKING_5.xlsx", encoding='utf-8-sig',  index=False)
```

I want for each person who has Wish == MT to double the score in Points Math column.

I tried:

```
df.loc[df['Wish'] == 'MT', 'Points Math'] = df.loc[df['Points Math'] * 2]
```

but this didn't work. I als tried to do an if statement, for loop but they didn't work either.
What's the appropriate sytax to do the logic?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
df['Points_Math'] = np.where(df['Wish'] == 'MT', df['Points Math'] * 2, df['Points Math'])
```

A new column would be created `'Points_Math'` with desired results or you can overwrite by replacing `'Points_Math'` with `'Points Math'`